# How to do Pagination using Freemarker and Spring?

Tags: spring, pagination, freemarker

I have a Freemarker template displaying a list of things, now I want to add some pagination.

I have changed the server-side code so that I can put into the backing form the page number (default 1) and page size (default 20) along with a bunch of query parameters. The Controller will handle this correctly and return the list of things, the page number and the last page number in the model.

But what I don't know (as I haven't done much web layer stuff before) is what to do in the template so that the user can click on next/previous/page-3 etc.

The template currently has:

```
<button type="submit" id="searchButton">Search</button>
```

I guess I could add buttons for each of the actions, but how could I then detect in the controller which button was clicked?

Cheers
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add an `onClick` event on buttons (or `A HREF` links) in your template, linked to a bit of Javascript that sets a value for a hidden element in the page. This element (say `ACTION`) would hold the value of which button you clicked (`NEXT` or `PREVIOUS`), so that on the server side, the controller can do the right thing according to the value of ACTION.

```
form.elements["ACTION"].value = 'NEXT'
```

Or that could also be a `PAGE` element, which holds the target number of the page (if you want to allow direct linking to all pages)

So if you're currently on page 4:

```
form.elements["PAGE"].value = '5' // for the 'NEXT' button
form.elements["PAGE"].value = '3' // for the 'PREVIOUS' button
```

Comment: This works: <a onclick="requestedPage.value=1;queryForm.submit()">page1</a>